# How to make a button that doesn't submit a form html

Tags: html, css

Hi I am currently working on a page where the user can edit their profile. Essentially the page is one big form with few buttons that have nothing to do with the form, as in they do things like cancel the edit profile entirely and redirect the user. The problem is I cannot make a button within the form that is independent of it. I also can't have it outside the form because then it wouldn't be in its proper div for CSS. What should I do? And why is it that you can't have nested forms? It seems to be logical as any input tag would just apply to the most recent form scope.

Thanks

Comment: I want the button to link somewhere is the thing so I can't use the button tag because it doesn't support href. I need to make a new form but I can't do that inside of another form.

Comment: Can you use javascript? @ColmanKoivisto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This button does not submit the form.

```
<button type='button'>Do something</button>
```

This does submit the form because the default `type` of a button is `submit`.

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

**EDIT:**

If you can use `Javascript` you can do this.

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';">Google</button>
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks

Comment: @ColmanKoivisto please accept the answer if it helped you!